# An identity is true for finite permutation groups, but is it true for infinite ones?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-isomorphism, infinite-groups, direct-product

If an arbitrary permutation group $P$ on a set $X\cup Y$ with $X\cap Y=\emptyset$ has two subgroups $G,H\subseteq P$ where $G$ is a permutation group on $X$ and $H$ is a permutation group on $Y$ satisfying $P\cong G\times H$ where $\times$ is the group direct product. Is it always true we must have:

$$P=\{\sigma\cup \phi\in \text{Sym}(X\cup Y):(\sigma,\phi)\in G\times H\}$$

Where $\sigma\cup \phi$ is the standard union of binary relations interpreting $\sigma$ and $\phi$ as functionals relations. So that $(\sigma\cup \phi)(t)=\sigma(t)$ if $t\in X$ and $(\sigma\cup \phi)(t)=\phi(t)$ if $t\in Y$. I mean I think it it is. At the very least its clearly true for finite groups since $\sigma\in G\land \phi\in H\implies \sigma\cup \phi\in P$ therefore we have $\{\sigma\cup \phi\in \text{Sym}(X\cup Y):(\sigma,\phi)\in G\times H\}\subseteq P$ and since we assumed the group $P$ was finite that $|\{\sigma\cup \phi\in \text{Sym}(X\cup Y):(\sigma,\phi)\in G\times H\}|=|G\times H|=|P|$ which means they must be equal. However what about the cases when $P$ isn't a finite group? Also if this is true, then why would anyone bother using the group direct product to express the isomorphism between products of permutation subgroups when they could write the definition out explicitly by the above identity? I also get the feeling this might be rather trivial, in which case I apologies for wasting anyone's time.

Comment: I think what you are asking is trivially true, but it is hard to be certain because you have not written the hypothesis sufficiently formally. As written the hypothesis is simply false, because it is not true that any permutation group $P$ has that property. Also, a permutation of $X$ is not a priori a permutation of $X \cup Y$, so you need to explain more precisely what you mean.

Comment: Repacing "any permutation group" by "anarbitrary permutation group" does not help. Your hypothesis is false. You should write something like "Let $P$ be a permutation group on $X \cup Y$ with the following property.".

Comment: Re: "Also, a permutation of $X$ is not a priori a permutation of $X∪Y$". Yes but it is under the assumptions at the start since the direct product of two sub groups of a group is only isomorphic to the original group if they are each normal and their intersection is the trivial group with every element in said group expressible as their product. Now if a permutation mapped an element from $X$ to $Y$ it could neither be in $G$ nor $H$ since both only map elements from $X$ to $X$ and $Y$ to $Y$ respectively which would would mean $P\not\cong G\times H$ a contradiction. So it must be a priori.

Comment: A permutation of $X$ is by definition a bijection $X \to X$. For two maps to be equal they have to have the same domains and codomains, so this is not a bijection $X \cup Y \to X \cup Y$ if $Y$ is nonempty. It is clear what you mean, but with a convoluted question like this it is helpful to be precise. Anyway I have realised now that the answer is no.

Comment: @DerekHolt Not under the set theoretic definition of a function, their domains and outputs at each input need only be equal. Anyway using your categorical function definition this could just be avoid by appropriately restricting the domain of the permutation on $X\cup Y$ to the set $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false in general, because a group $F$ can be isomorphic to a proper subgroup $G$ of itself. For example you could have $K = \mathbb Z $ and $G =  2{\mathbb Z}$.

Then $P$ could have subgroups $G$ and $H$ as described (where $H$ can be any group), but $P=\{\sigma \cup  \phi  \in {\rm Sym}(X \cup Y):(σ,ϕ) \in F \times H\}$. So we have $P \cong G \times H$, but your equality is not true with $G$ in place of $F$.

OK, let's be more specific. We take $X = {\mathbb Z}$, $Y = \{y \}$ a set with a single element not in $X$, $F = \langle \sigma \rangle$ with $\sigma:n \mapsto n+1$ for $n \in X $, $G = \langle \sigma^2 \rangle$, $H$ the trivial group, and $P=\{\sigma \cup  \phi  \in {\rm Sym}(X \cup Y):(σ,ϕ) \in F \times H\}$.

Then $P \cong G \times H$ (an infinite cyclic group), but $P \ne \{\sigma \cup  \phi  \in {\rm Sym}(X \cup Y):(σ,ϕ) \in G \times H\}$.

Comment: But one of the requirements was $X\cap Y=\emptyset$?

Comment: I don't understand the answer, can you give me a contradiction involving permutation groups on sets as described. I really appreciate your effort I'm just having trouble understanding.

Comment: I am taking $H$ to be an arbitrary subgroup of ${\rm Sym}(Y)$ for a set $Y$ that is disjoint from $X$.

Comment: What permutation groups are $P$ and $G$? I'm sorry, I think I'm not being precise enough. Here is a simpler special case of what I'm asking, if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint and $G$ is a permutation group on $X\cup Y$ with $G\cong \text{Sym}(X)\times \text{Sym}(Y)$ then $G=\{\sigma\cup \phi:(\sigma,\phi)\in\text{Sym}(X)\times \text{Sym}(Y) \}$

Comment: @Ethan Unless I misunderstood, that's false even for finite groups.

Comment: @Derek Holt Yeah I see qudit, I'm tempted to close the question though I don't want to be a dick because Derek spent time helping me. My original intent was I was trying to describe sets of permutations on $X\cup Y$ whose orbits never contain any elements from $X\cap Y$. Would you mind if I deleted the question, @Derek? I didn't formulate my question properly and I can see now that it obviously isn't true, and I feel pretty dumb lol.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to delete a question with an accepted answer.